# jQuery scroll function is not recognizing change of variables

Tags: jquery, variables, scroll, append

I want to implement a jQuery scroll function onto my page which appends more data on a div when scrolled to the bottom of the page ONLY WHEN the user is on a certain category.

The category change is made on a variable "katcheck". The appending should only happen when katcheck == "k" and only then. But the scroll function once fired, won't listen to the change of the variable. 
Or in other words: when katcheck gets changed to something else, the scroll function still has katcheck saved as "k".

here is the code snippet:

```
var $start=8;
var $length=2;
$contentLoadTriggered = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($("#full-page-container").height() - $(window).height()) && $contentLoadTriggered == false && katcheck == "k")
    {
    alert(katcheck);
        $contentLoadTriggered = true;

        $.get('getgallery_by_kat2.php', { k_id:1, st:$start, ln:$length }, function(data) {

            $(data).hide().appendTo(".imgmain").fadeIn();          
            $contentLoadTriggered = false;
            $start=$start+2;   $("div#descri").hide();    
        });
    }
});
```

How can I make the scroll function recognize the variable change? The alert I put into the function proves that even if all other functions recognize the change, the scroll function does not.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The ajax query $.get() operates asynchronistically.

Meaning that will take it own time to complete it duties.

You can make sure that it has the correct  data by turning of the async mode.

Like so:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

and then perform your ajax calls using jQuery.get( ... );

then just turning it on again once

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

Comment: Thank you but how does this solve the problem since the $.get() query should not even be fired when the variable "katcheck" is not "k"?

Comment: I not sure from your comment whether that solved your problem. But what happens often is that asynch mode will mask variable changes. This is a big gotcha "bug", sometimes it worse when it happens intermittent. (BTW  I changed the variable names and fixed some spelling, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Your previous code did not solve my problem, there was no difference in the behaviour. Since I'm on my work atm I'll try the new one later and come back and let you know if it helped. But good to know about the bug. Never would have thought about that being the reason. Will come back later and respond. Thank you!